Render is always black
I'm a total noob to Blender although I have watched quite a few tutorials.
I would like to get a rendered image of a part I designed in 3D CAD.  I have imported the stl files, aligned the various parts, setup the camera, set up an area light and alternately applied an HDRI.  When I render, the output is completely black, right away.
I have watched about 10 videos on what the problem could be and I still haven't found it.  I have checked :

Renderer: Cycles
Use nodes: No
Film transparent: Yes
Cameras and lighting enabled: Yes
Film exposure: 1
Color management exposure: 0
Clipping end: 1000

Here is the file:

I am using version 3.6.15 as version 4.2 wouldn't install (I expect my graphics card isn't advanced enough, that or no GPU); I have an iMac from 2016.
Any other settings that I should check ?  Thanks in advance for any ideas !

Upload the file to https://blend-exchange.com/ and add that to the edit

can you render the default cube?

maybe change the camera cutoff distance or make it start at 0.001m

Hi @Kaleb Claussen, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment."

I would suggest you start all over again because, at least on my old PC, trying to work with a vase that is 286m high is just crazy. So when importing into Blender, in Blender's STL import panel change the scale to 0.001.

BTW, for me the glass vase etc did not render all black. it seemed to render .....meh "ok". For the materials, in the Shader Editor, instead of using fancy shader node setups start with simple ones like for the glass material just add a Glass BSDF node and connect it directly to the Material output node. For the Carafe skirt only the Principled BSDF connected to the Material Output node and just change the Base Color and Roughness value. In the Shader editor, World node setup disconnect that Magic Texture. Keep every thing simple until you have a basic render working.

For rendering, Render Properties panel, Render Engine > Cycles. If you have a GPU then set Device to GPU. For quick test renders set Sampling > Render > Max Samples to only 24. and uncheck the Denoise option. When you think you are ready to do a more final render then you can bump up the Max Samples to a higher value. ( And no need to have Sampling > Viewport > Max Samples set to a high value either unless you have a beast of a GPU.)All above suggestions are found in this .blend file 

I am using Blender 4.2.1 so if the file I linked to still is not rendering then try downloading the latest version of Blender.

There is no such thing as a 2016 iMac, but even the first one from 2015 seems to meet Blender 4.2's requirements, even for GPU rendering on Cycles though with limitations due to using Metal on AMD + this old GPU being based on GCN3 which Metal apparently supports with its own limitations. So make sure your system is up-to-date, and you should be able to run 4.2.

No issues rendering on my side with 4.2.2, 3.6.14 and 3.6.16. Though admittedly that's on Windows, not Mac OS.

@greanie We need updates from you. It seems this renders just fine on others machines. However, I don't have an imac so that is likely where something is different. Have you tried rendering with box CPU and GPU?

You are right Lauloque, there is no such thing as an iMac from 2016, boy you sure are on top of your Mac stats, bravo.  My iMac is 2013, it's my MacBook that is 2016, my bad.  (Wait, Lauloque is there such a thing ?) Blender 4.2.1 wouldn't install on my iMac and my MacBook isn't powerful enough for Blender, so I'm on 3.6.15.
I've got it rendering ! I needed to turn on "Use Nodes" and I needed to enable the nodes, two of my color nodes were not enabled, it seems.  Didn't help that I couldn't figure out how to see the node tree, I had to go to global view. Thanks for all your ideas everyone !
